# Selecting image region based on boolean image mask values

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I have a rgb image, for example

```
img_rgb[:,:,0] = [ 125 160; 130 125];
img_rgb[:,:,1] = [ 125 160; 130 125];
img_rgb[:,:,2] = [ 125 160; 130 125];
```

and a mask boolean image whose size equals the size of img_rgb e.g

```
mask[:,:] = [ 1 0; 0 1]
```

for every zero value of mask, I would like to associate a nan value in the img-rgb, thus obtaining the following

```
img_rgb[:,:,0] = [ 125 nan; nan 125]
img_rgb[:,:,1] = [ 125 nan; nan 125]
img_rgb[:,:,2] = [ 125 nan; nan 125]
```

Since my image array is really big (length size 10000px) I would like to do that as fast as possible and thus avoiding a double for cycle. In Matlab I would use the logical operator

```
img_rgb(repmat(mask,1,1,3)==0)=nan;
```

how can I do something similar in python? python v.2.7
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) arrays, you can use boolean indexing similar to Matlab in python.

[Broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) will take care of the repmat for you. So you can do just:

```
import numpy as np

img_rgb[mask == 0] = np.Nan
```